# chalice-cognito-auth obtained id_token but still getting "User is not authorized"

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, chalice, awscognitotoken

Try to use https://pypi.org/project/chalice-cognito-auth/

I was able to get a json response like:

```json
{"id_token":"eyJra...sda",
"refresh_token":"eyJjd...",
"access_token":"eyJraWQiO...",
"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

But when I try to use it like

```
curl -H "Authorization: id_token value ..." http://127.0.0.1:8000/whoami
```

It replied

```
{
    "Message": "User is not authorized to access this resource"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer id_token" http://127.0.0.1:8000/whoami`

i.e., you missed the `Bearer` keyword.

Comment: I tried this as well, still does not work